# A group $G$ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $G$ if $P_{G}(H)$ strictly contains $H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The permutizer of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $G$ that permute with$H$, i.e. $P_{G}(H)= \langle x \in G | \langle x\rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $G$ if $P_{G}(H)$ strictly contains $H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

A group $G$ is said to $satisfy$ the maximal permutizer condition if $P_{G}(M)=G$ for any maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ and $P_{G}(M)=G$ .Then there exists an element $x \in G/M $  such that $G= \langle x \rangle M= M \langle x \rangle$, which implies that $M$ has a cyclic supplement in $G$.Hence $G$ is soluble.
  $Z_{n}$ is a example for this groups. What other examples are there for this?

Comment: Any supersolvable group (because its maximal subgroups have prime index).

Comment: The dihedral group $D_8$ is supersolvable but isn't satisfy in this theorem.

Comment: I don't understand. What theorem?

Comment: Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ and $P_{G}(M)=G$ .Then there exists an element $x \in G/M $  such that $G= \langle x \rangle M= M \langle x \rangle$, which implies that $M$ has a cyclic supplement in $G$.Hence $G$ is soluble.

Comment: But why do you say that $D_8$ doesn't satisfy this theorem?

Comment: Look at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404908000595 Remark.
$G$ satisfies the permutizer condition if $G$ is supersoluble.

Comment: I calculated $P_{G}(M)$ but it is not equal by G. For maximal permutier condition $P_{G}(M)=G$

Comment: Well you must have made a mistake then. If $M$ is any maximal subgroup of any group $G$ and $|G:M|$ is prime, then $P_G(M)=G$.